# How to adjust the Exif timestamp of a photo using the date in its name

Tags: filenames, android, timestamps, file-metadata, exif

I'm trying to get the filename of a screenshot on an Android phone (which contains the date it was taken) as a string and add it to the Exif timestamp of that screenshot (which doesn't seem to have been recorded when those screenshots were taken).

All the filenames of these photos follows the same template: `Screenshot_YYYYMMDD-******.png`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: There is no EXIF in a PNG image, that's why you can't find one.

Comment: It's not a standard, but *of course* you can store EXIF-metadata into a PNG-File. It won't be recognized by all programs, as the standardization wasn't successfull. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576717/2768231)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, use [exiftool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). Under Debian/Ubuntu this can be installed with

```
sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

Something like this should work (assuming the *** show the time):

```
exiftool "-datetimeoriginal<filename" Screenshot_YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.png
```

exiftool detects the dateformat on its own, you can look at the current EXIF metadata (and some more by simply calling the tool with the filename:

```
exiftool Screenshot_YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.png
```

If you have a filename which can't be automatically read by exiftool, you can use the -d Parameter to clear things up for exiftool. Again, for your example:

```
exiftool "-datetimeoriginal<filename" -d Screenshot_%Y%m%d-%H%M%S Screenshot_YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.png
```